# Magento 1: How can I restore the relationship between simpleproduct and configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade

Is there a way to set the `link` between the `simple product`s and the `configurable product` via `script` or `database`? Some relations were `lost` during a `DB repair`.

(There is only one backup of the corrupted DB - the previous developer has not upgraded cleanly from `Magento 1.7 to 1.9`)

Comment: Manual restoration is quite tough, Your hosting provide may help to recover your data If they take regular backups

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. When this information is gone, it must be restored either by manual linking or by importing it. Exactly the same problem I had eight months ago.